# Oracle SQL Function using data from another schema says table or view does not exist

Tags: sql, function, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Im trying to create a function which takes in 3 parameters and returns one. The value of the returned parameter is obtained by querying two tables, however, one of the tables is on a different schema. The SQL im using is below:

```
create or replace FUNCTION tester
    (
    originaltext IN VARCHAR2, lang IN VARCHAR2, category IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL) 
  RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  translatedttextval VARCHAR2(255) := '';
BEGIN
  --if category is null, disregard category
  if category is null then
      SELECT distinct nvl(trans.translatedtext, originaltext) 
      INTO translatedttext
      FROM tbl_translations trans, SECDEVSCHEMA.tbl_instanceids ids 
      WHERE trans.translatedlang = ids.id_a
      AND ids.name = lang
      AND trans.originaltext = originaltext;
  end if;
  RETURN translatedttextval;
END;
```

I've removed a bit of the query here which searches with category because it does something similar and has the same issue.

So, when I run this and pass in the params, I get an error which reads:
Error(16,46): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

If I do the following query it works fine when not on the SECDEVSCHEMA and returns the reults from tbl_instanceids which is on the SECDEVSCHEMA schema:

```
SELECT * FROM SECDEVSCHEMA.tbl_instanceids ids WHERE ids.id_a = 1234555;
```

I don't have DBA access to the DB but if I need some select priviledge granted or something I can get it done. Not sure if this the case though as the above query works.

Small additional question also:
where it says in the query
    nvl(trans.translatedtext, originaltext)

If i wanted to surround the original text value with brackets when no translatedtext value exists, how would I go about this?

I'm using SQL Developer by the way in case that's important.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was down to a priviledges issue.

In SQL Developer, I expanded the tables package and selected the table I needed access to in the Function, right clicked and selected Priviledges > Grant.

As this is just a Development DB I just assigned all the priviledges to the appropriate schema or User and its working now.

Still unsure about this part though:

> Small additional question also: where it says in the query nvl(trans.translatedtext, originaltext)
>
> If i wanted to surround the original text value with brackets when no translatedtext value exists, how would >I go about this?

Any takers for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for your smaller question

```
nvl(trans.translatedtext, '<'|| originaltext ||'>' )
```